# Device Driver Development in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, device-driver

I plan to learn embedded linux and writing linux device drivers.
After reading about device drivers and walking through some tutorials, I'm a little confused about the kernel-source that to be used for compilation.

I am using ubuntu 11.04 and in my `/usr/src/` me find the following:

> tijin@tijin-Vostro-460:/usr/src$ ls
>
> gcc-4.4                  linux-headers-2.6.38-10-generic-pae
>   linux-headers-2.6.38-10  linux-headers-2.6.38-8

my questions:

1)do I need a kernel-source to compile the driver code or the headers are enough?

2)where can I get the kernel source code and what is the procedure to install the source code. Please let me know the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Headers is enough
2. from [kernel.org](http://kernel.org) - or for Ubuntu specific kernels, follow the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile)

For module compilation instructions, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133338/makefile-for-linux-kernel-module)

Comment: thanks for your answer. can you please add the steps to compile a sample driver code with headers?

Comment: successfully loaded hello world module. but i tried to see the logs in /var/log/messages but getting:there is no such file or directory. where i can see the logs, can you help me ? thanks in advance.

Comment: yes..its working. i found another way to see the logs: $tail -f /var/log/kern.log  //Kernel logs. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. You need not only the source but a "make"d source (a compiled kernel source).
2. The main location to get the kernel source is: http://www.kernel.org

As you're using Ubuntu you can just download the source from the repositories.
Here's the page indicated at Ubuntu's help as a guide for compiling a kernel from source on Natty (11.04):
http://blog.avirtualhome.com/2011/08/03/how-to-compile-a-new-ubuntu-11-04-natty-kernel/

Answer (score 0):

For a fresher to device driver coding the "hello world" driver code reference is here :

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/simple-makefile-error-all-nothing-need-to-be-done-600403/ .
 This link also discussing the issues related to the Makefile. Important idea that i got from  the reference is: Never ever copy-paste the content of a document for creating  Makefile.

If you are getting trouble with seeing logs then please refer the link :

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-log-files-location-and-how-do-i-view-logs-files/

thanks.